# Is it possible to have a WCF service host not bound to any specific service type?

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding

This post is somewhat connected to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890284/how-to-create-custom-wcf-binding-which-effectively-reverses-the-communication).

In short, I am trying to build a reverse polling http binding where the host polls its clients for requests. I am using the code from http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/duplexhttp as my reference. Now, in this binding the  host is actually a client and the clients are actually servers. Which means, a client using this reverse polling http binding must end up with a hidden Service Host providing the channel pump facility.

Now, the usual pattern of using the ServiceHost type demands the presence of the actual WCF service implementation. In my case, the ServiceHost is open at the client - it does not have the service implementation and rightfully so.

I am wondering what is the best way to solve this problem?

Ideally, this service host needs no service. The polling host sends Message instances, which are not mapped to any service contract. These Messages are requested and replied to by dedicated channels - HttpPollingRequestChannel and HttpPollingReplyChannel respectively. But I need the service host for the channel pump facility it implements.

### Edit 1

I guess more background information is necessary to clarify the picture. Our system consists of clients, the server and agents. Clients talk to the server, the latter communicates their requests to the agents, which communicate the results back to the server. All the channels are straightforward HTTP - simple and clear.

However, there is a demand to be able to deploy agents behind firewall with no ability to open inbound ports on it. This means, that the Server --> Agent communication is no longer possible. As I see it, I have two choices:

1. Redesign the Server --> Agent protocol to make it use polling.
2. Implement low level binding, which would use polling internally.

What choice would you make? Although, the second choice is harder to implement this is a one time effort. But it has numerous benefits. Is it possible? I think yes, because polling duplex http binding already exists both for Silverlight and for .NET - see the link in the beginning to this post.

### Edit 2

I wish to stress again, that **I do not want duplex**. In duplex communication, the callback is executed in the context of the request, meaning Agent sends request and the Server performs the callback. My case is different. Agent sends nothing. The server decides out of the blue to communicate with the Agent. There is no active request on behalf of Agent. So, the existing duplex binding is not good for me, but I am trying to learn from it how to implement the polling.

The overall picture is this:

- Agent constantly polls the Server
- If Server wants to send a message to the Agent, that message waits for the next polling request and rides to the Agent on top of the polling request reply.

The polling requests are not part of any interface, they are implemented in a low level binding infrastructure.

Comment: If agent is behind firewall it must be the one who initiates connection = it must be a client of the service hosted on server.

Comment: I want to keep the polling hidden as low as possible. When it is inside the binding. it lets me quickly reconfigure the agent to use the regular binding if there are no firewall issues.

Comment: Still don't get it. Who is initiating communcation in your case and what are your requirements / limitations.

Comment: The agent publishes itself with the known servers. After that it sits idle waiting for requests, which originate at the clients, go through the server, which "dispatches" them to the relevant agents. I have deliberately enclosed dispatches in quotes, because when the agent is behind firewall, the agent itself polls the known servers for the work to do. But logically, it is the server which contacts the agent. And this is what actually happens when firewall is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, [I would not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265033/mysterious-problem-in-wcf-and-iis/4265457#4265457) use duplex if I were you.

In addition to a whole host of threading issues, if server and client are equivalent in terms of weight and authority, I would use 2 separate interfaces one for server to clients and the other clients back to server.

WCF might not be exactly the way to go if you need full flexibility on the message. **CQRS + NServiceBus** might be more suitable which defines commands and each message will mandate the action which is required to be done upon it.

Comment: Added clarification in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you are wasting your time. The technology is not prepared for that. If you want duplex communication with clients use Publish/subscribe pattern. If you want just server to call clients expose service on clients and user server as client of that services.

Why?

1. It will save you enormous amount of time and budget
2. It will work - it is tested by thousands of real world solutions
3. People will understand it and help you if you have troubles.

If you really need to follow your scenarion give up with WCF and use other programming model - probably sockets directly.

**Edit:**

Ok if you still want to use duplex service I have this idea:

- Use `WsDualHttpBinding` when agent is not behind firewall
- Use `PollingDualHttpBinding` when agent is behind firewall - to get this binding you must install Silverlight 4 SDK. It is in separate assembly System.ServiceModel.PollingDuplex.dll. You must register binding as new binding extension if you want to use it in config file.

Comment: Added clarification in the body of the question.

Comment: Edited my question once again.

Comment: @mark: In such case you can reverse engineere `PollingDualHttpBinding` but my former answer is still valid - I'm 99% sure that you are wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

Firewalls are the reason why duplex HTTP doesn't work. Given the number of times this very problem comes up, I really wish Microsoft would have never created dualHttpBinding.

The solution for this is to use something like netTcpBinding instead, as that one allows actual duplex communication over a single connection (the one the client creates), thus solving the firewall problem. If for some reason you need to use HTTP though, your only option is to have the agents poll the service.

Comment: How can one use net.tcp:// ? Is it utilizing port 80? Because if it is not, then it would not work at all, because of the firewall. Usually only ports 80 and 443 are open and even them sometimes are open for outbound only.

Comment: I suppose you could put it on port 80 if you wanted to and didn't have a webserver on the server, but you're telling me that your SERVER only has port 80 open and you can't change it? The clients don't need open ports, they simply need to be able to create outbound connections, and most firewalls should allow that unless they're set to be incredibly restrictive.

Comment: I am not talking about clients. The server has 80 and/or 443, inbound and outbound - that's it. No one will let you add more ports in an enterprise. The agents have 80 and/or 443 outbound and sometimes 80 and/or 443 inbound, but sometimes not. Aside of ports dedicated to particular business applications all the rest is closed and will not be open for our app, which should be able to do just fine over HTTP(S).

Comment: How I long for the olden days when sysadmins would ask "why do you need that port?" and not just blindly open 80 and close everything else no matter how little sense it makes. With the restrictions you have, you've got no choice but to do polling. HTTP doesn't work the way that real duplex communication requires.

Comment: Yes, that is the given. Now the question how to deal with it.